# How do send a OTP using Firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, sms, one-time-password

I have tried flutter_otp plugin but it does not support null safety how can I send a OTP with Firebase in flutter

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to setup firebase follow this link otherwise follow next step

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-firebase-setup

After Firebase SetUp you need to follow this step

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/